# Convert string til LateX image?

Tags: windows-phone-7, math, latex, expression

I'm developing a WP7 app that has a lot of math content, and I need to display expressions as images. 
The data for these expressions is in the form of strings like this:

```
"d=\\sqrt{2} \\times a"
"A=a \\times \\frac{\\pi}{4}"
```

etc.

The goal is to take a string like this, run it through some parser of some sort that then outputs an image of the expression in LateX style.

Does anyone know of some magic code I can include / have a solution?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If these images are part of the app then perhaps these are useful [How to export a equation as a image without background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/how-to-export-a-equation-as-a-image-without-background/35696#35696) and [TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/34058#34058)

Comment: I think the best way will be to deliver the formulas as XAML files with the app: https://www.bennyn.de/programmierung/windows-phone/latex-formeln-in-xaml-code-umwandeln.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution without getting Tex to run on windows 7 phone, would be to use a web service.

You would post your equation string to a web service and it would reply with the image data or a url. [Example](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/)

In the event that tex for windows 7 phone exists, that above mentioned page also links to a script called tex2im which shows how to create an image from tex code.

Comment: TeX doesnt exist I'm afraid, and a web service is not ideal unfortunately. 
I still haven't found a solution to my problem, anyone is free to speak up :)